# Problem animating chameleon-like eyes

Tags: animation, armature

I'm relatively new to everything involved with 3D modeling and I'm having some issues with animation in particular.

[image: Eyes]

I'm attempting to have these "Eyes" animate, looking in all different directions; kinda like how a chameleon's eyes work. Problem is that I want them to all move at the same exact time and loop. I also want room for other animations in the future.

I've only been able to get one eye at a time to animate in the action editor, and I've tried an armature but I keep messing up somewhere down the line.

Right now I have all the eyes separated from the main mesh and from each other, I don't know if its easier or harder to animate them that way.

I've been at this for about two hours now and still no luck. I'm going to sleep on it and fiddle with it more in the morning. I'm sure its probably just something simple that I'm messing up but its late and I figured I'd ask here just in case someone was willing to help.

Ty for the help!

EDIT: Right, it was late last night so I didn't clarify actually what I wanted (Although the comments did help me discover something that'd be useful in the future):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmWm2.jpg

This is about what I want to happen, to have the "eyes" move erratically to sort of scan the scene. I can have them all animated separately, but I'd rather it'd be all done in one action. Is that possible?

Comment: How are you trying to animate the eyes and what challenges did you encounter?

Comment: If you want all eyes to move ate the same time and look at the same target, create an empty to use as the target and use a constraint (a "look at" constraint, I believe it's called), so you just have to animate the "target" (the empty) and all the eyes will follow.

Comment: If you don't want them to look to the same target, I would do the same as I said before but with a different target for each eye.

Comment: You must be talking about Track To or Damped Track constraint. I think the question is a bit too vague, Insomnia should show what he wants with just 3 or 4 eyes and jst several pictures

Comment: You're right, it's "track to" in blender. "Look at" is the name of the constraint in 3ds Max.